# How to set query params while using location.go() method

Tags: angular

I am using location class from @angular/common package.
but how to set multiple query parameters along with the path.
I have tried the below code

```
this.location.go(LAYOUT_ROUTES_NAMES.PROJECTS + '/subprojects', 'pname=' + name + '&pid=' + pid);
```

but i am not able to read the queryparams data using route.queryparams.subscribe(--) method.
From angular docs below code is available.

```
/**
     * Changes the browsers URL to a normalized version of the given URL, and pushes a
     * new item onto the platform's history.
     *
     * @param path  URL path to normalizze
     * @param query Query parameters
     * @param state Location history state
     *
     */
    go(path: string, query?: string, state?: any): void;
```

Comment: try using router.navigate instead ? https://angular.io/guide/router

Comment: initially i have used router.navigate but api calls are getting cancelled so i have moved to location.go(-)

Comment: have you tried figuring out why the calls are getting cancelled? 
Angular Docs "Note: it's better to use Router service to trigger route changes. Use Location only if you need to interact with or create normalized URLs outside of routing."